# Make taskbar stay in the background?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

*Is it possible in Windows 10 to configure the taskbar to stay in the background?* (like on Windows XP)

This means that if a Window is overlapping with the taskbar, the taskbar will *not* come to front even when moving the mouse to the bottom of the screen. To make the taskbar come to front, one can press for example the Windows key. The advantage is that it simply stays out of the way all the time when a window is maximized.

The ideal solution is one that doesn't require installation of an extra utility.

Comment: I think we all know this would require a 3rd party utility.

Comment: Set the taskbar to "auto-hide" and it will only appear when you mouse down to its vicinity.

Comment: @Moab Maybe it's possible to change a registry key?

Comment: @JohnCanon This is exactly not what I want. Under Windows XP it was possible to keep the taskbar behind all other windows, so that it does not appear when moving the pointer down.

Comment: Move the taskbar to left/right ;)

Comment: @feklee I can find nothing on it. :-(